# Pass a static string parameter (a model choice) through URL in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-testing, django-tests

Django 2.0

I've got the following model:

```
class Visitor(models.Model):
    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('P', 'Person'),
        ('E', 'Employee'),
    )
    type = models.CharField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES, max_length=1)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    birth_date = models.DateField()
    street_address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

In my URLs I have the following URL:

```
# ex: /my_app/P/visit_information/
path('<str:visitor_type>/visit_information/', views.visit_information, name='visit_information'),
```

I'm trying to write some tests for this and am running into an issue.

I'd like my test to just tell me if it returns status 200:

```
def test_parent_visit_information_returns_200(self):
    """
    visit_information page returns a 200
    """
    client = Client()
    response = client.get(reverse('visit_information', args={'visitor_type':'P'}))
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

But I get the following error:

```
visit_information() got an unexpected keyword argument 'visitor_type'
```

What is the best way to handle doing a reverse lookup on that? How can I provide it either a 'P' or an 'E', so it would return the 200 code?

Am I handling the URL improperly in the test?

*Edited to add*:

If I try `kwargs` instead of `args` I see this error:

`visit_information() got an unexpected keyword argument 'visitor_type'`

*Edited to add view*:

```
def visit_information(request):
    return render(request, 'my_app/visit_information.html', {

    })
```

Comment: Have you tried passing `kwargs` instead of `args`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried both kwargs and args - both give the same answer.

Comment: Could you show the visit_information() view?

Comment: I've edited to add the view - it's a really, really simple view as I'm just getting this app going. It's just some HTML that says "displaying the view"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `{'visitor_type':'P'}` is a dictionary, so you should be using `kwargs`, not `args`:

```
response = client.get(reverse('visit_information', kwargs={'visitor_type':'P'}))
```

Alternatively, you could use `args` with a list:

```
response = client.get(reverse('visit_information', args=['P']}))
```

Once you've fixed that, you're getting the `TypeError` because your `visit_information` view is missing the `visitor_type` from its signature. It should be:

```
def visit_information(request, visitor_type):
    return render(request, 'my_app/visit_information.html', {})
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - I appreciate it! A real 'duh' moment for me. Thanks again!